# Proving that a USB Device is "Dead"

Tags: usb, drivers, hardware-failure

I recently purchased a used USB receiver online.  Upon plugging the receiver into my PC, I found it strange that Windows did not attempt to locate drivers for the new device.  I checked the device manager, and nothing new appears in there.  I tried installing the official drivers from the manufacturer, and still nothing is recognized.  Tried different USB ports and an entirely different machine to no avail.  It appears the hardware is just not functioning whatsoever.

My problem, however, is that the party that sold me the device refuses to believe that the issue is hardware related and insists I have some sort of driver issue.  Is there any way that I can concretely "prove" to this person that the hardware is broken via a screenshot, picture, video, or otherwise?

Comment: What do you mean by "receiver"? You mean like a Logitech universal receiver?

Comment: It's a receiver from Microsoft for wireless game controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you plug the device in to the PC, show them a screenshot of the Device Manager. If the device was detected, but with no drivers, it would appear under a category called "Other devices", have a generic name, and have a yellow question mark for its icon.

You can try pressing the Scan for Hardware Changes button to see if any new devices pop up. It may also be worth updating your chipset drivers.

Another solution would be to call back and speak with another technician who will be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the best I can do.  Unfortunately I don't have the option to talk to another technician, since I purchased it from eBay.

Comment: If you think the seller is trying to scam you by selling a defective item, you can file a dispute with eBay. You're SOL if the item was sold as-is though.

Comment: We're currently in the dispute stage of eBay's claim process, and it's been a hopeless back and forth with the seller.  I came to SU hoping to find some undeniable proof from my end :)

Comment: Ask the seller, "What proof would you accept to indicate the device is not functioning?"

Answer (score 0):

Connect it to the all available USB-ports on different devices. If no responce then device is dead.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something that I can show to the other party that concretely says the device is dead.  I have already told them verbally that I have done what you said, but they insist the issue is still software related (i.e. I don't have the correct driver).

Comment: The "party" doesn't want to believe you.  Not much you can do about that.